# Could not find file commons-beanutils.jar to copy

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, jar

I'm doing project using JSF, Hibernate, and Spring. Because I'm a newbie, I try to follow tutorial and download it. here is the link http://harishkv.blogspot.com/2009/12/spring-jsf-hibernate-integration-part-3.html Now, I have the problem to run it. 
I get an error

> D:\netbeans_project\LinkedLinks_Part2_SpringJSF\LinkedLinks\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1037:
>   Warning: Could not find file
>   D:\netbeans_project\LinkedLinks_Part2_SpringJSF\LinkedLinks\lib\jsf12\commons-beanutils.jar
>   to copy.

Whereas, I put the jar in lib folder and in jsf12 (I make it manually).
How to solve this problem so I can run it?
Thank you. Your answer is very appreciated.

Comment: The root cause is on the server log. The specified JAR file, `commons-beanutils.jar` is unavailable. Did you precisely add it to the class-path?

Comment: Tiny, to which classpath do you mean?

Comment: If I where you I would try to find a newer tutorial.

Comment: yapp, I did what you say. but i always end with no result. May you show me the recommended tutorial about those 3 frameworks without using maven?